# Import _Installation.json of Parse.com Export

Tags: parse-platform

how can I import the exported _Installation-data? When I try to set the classname to _Installation, I just get the error "cannot import into this special class"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, this feature has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround so far: Iterating over the exported _Installation.json and recreating the objects via POST against https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_Installation .
This is no real backup restore as this creates new objectIds, createdAts and updatedAts but better than nothing.